# How can I typeset this particular Devnagari character?

Tags: unicode, indic, alphabet

I am comfortable with using all of the Devnagari script. However, I'm finding it difficult to use the letters "श" and "श्री"; the former is present in Devnagari, whereas the latter isn't. How can I typeset "श्री"? Should I use `\dn` somehow?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Could you clarify?

Comment: Keep in mind, that most of us can't read that. But you can always refer to them adding their unicode point. श (DEVANAGARI LETTER SHA, U+0936)

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid that the answer is probably negative. From your question I infer that you are using the Velthuis devanagari package (because it has the \dn switch to devanagari) and you want to get the irregular ligature depicted here: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E0%A4%B6%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0

Browsing through the tables at the end of the documentation, I cannot find this particular ligature in the supported set of ligatures or special characters. So the sequence with the virama seems to be the (admittedly ugly) way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
{\dn f} {\dn \399wF}
```

for "श" and "श्री".